# What are the best practices when colaborating with an audio engineer?

Tags: audio

I am talking with various audio engineers and each has pretty much their own rates and way of colaborating. Since I am pretty foreign to their world and work process, I want to have a healthy relationship, and a fair money/work exchange.

Thus I want to inquire on the copyright use of the music. Naturally, the first would be the right to use all the sountracks in the game, for trailers, promotional material, conventions.

Secondary, I am thinking explicit permission for streamers and youtubers & the like to use the music for their edited videos and as background music while playing or streaming, as long as they give credit and link to the website or game page.

Thirdly, the right to sell the music, as an addon, on the game page.

Different sound engineers expressed explicit fobidding the second and/or third bulletpoint, and I am sure there is a fourth and fith, sixth...etc. that I am missing. So my question is a bit more complex.

I am open to suggestions on improving my question, perhaps I failed to get the message through.

Comment: With a work-for-hire the whole copyright is usually transferred to the client. This is specifically to avoid this copyright nightmare.

Comment: @Philipp thanks for the reply Phillipp! Most of them want to sell their game album on their own website and have a sense of ownership on their own work. I sympathise but I am afraid it might backfire. Some forbid sellin on the game's page and only want to sell it on their site.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright really is a nightmare. There are very possessive sound engineers with their work, but not all are like that. I am a sound engineer and to avoid me that problem. I prefer to charge for all the work, once, including license to resell (With a contract between), and the developer is responsible to use it as he wants.